# When is @RequestParam annotation not needed in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm looking through some Spring 3 MVC controller code and I see that @RequestParam is used for some parameters and not for others. Example where it is not being used:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/experiments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getExperimentsPage(ExperimentSearchCriteria criteria, Map<String, Object> model) {
    // method body here
}
```

When is @RequestParam (or similar parameter-specifying annotation) not needed?

Comment: My testing reveals that if you include a non annotated parameter on a `@Controller` "action" method, Spring will attempt to bind similarly named request parameters (and ignore that parameter otherwise). But it's probably best to be explicit and use the `@RequestParam` annotation when you intend to populate an action method argument using a request parameter. Certainly it gives you more control that way in terms of being able to tune the usage via `@RequestParam`'s attributes such as default and required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about your question, but you only need `@RequestParam` when you want to bind a method argument with a parameter held by the request.

I think this is pretty clear [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam).

Comment: From my testing, if @RequestParam is not specified on an Object parameter, Spring MVC will by default try to bind to the internal properties of that object.

Answer (score 20):

Good question, I have been wondering this too until I found it being mentioned in the doc:

> Note that use of @RequestParam is optional, e.g. to set its
>   attributes. By default any argument that is a simple value type, as
>   determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, and is not resolved by any
>   other argument resolver, is treated as if it was annotated with
>   @RequestParam.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Most of time, I don't specify this unless my method parameter name is different with request parameter, or, if the value is optional, I will need to use `required=false`.

Comment: your reply is better than Dani.

Comment: You can also do not specify `@RequestParam` for optional parameters if you are using `Optional<T>` as parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

@RequestParam is used to pass query parameters.

Example: http://localhost:8080/employee/get?status=ACTIVE

Here we can get status with below code

@RequestParam(value="status") String status

We have some properties like required, defaultValue etc. If you provide required=false as mentioned in below line of code, the status parameter is not mandatory in URL

@RequestParam(value="status",required=false)

The URL will be like http://localhost:8080/employee/get